# Prove the comparison test for convergence of real valued series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Let $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b_{n}$ be two formal series of real numbers, and suppose that $|a_{n}|\leq b_{n}$ for all $n\geq m$. Then if $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b_{n}$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, and in fact
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}\right| \leq \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}|a_{n}| \leq \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b_{n}.
\end{align*}

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\sum_{n=m}^{M}b_{n}$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequence. Consequently, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
q\geq p\geq N & \Rightarrow \left|\sum_{n=m}^{q}b_{n} - \sum_{n=m}^{p}b_{n}\right| = \left|\sum_{n=p+1}^{q}b_{n}\right|\leq \varepsilon\\\\
& \Rightarrow \left|\sum_{n = p+1}^{q}a_{n}\right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=p+1}^{q}|a_{n}|\right| \leq\left|\sum_{n=p+1}^{q}b_{n}\right|\leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

whence we conclude that $\sum_{n=m}^{M}|a_{n}|$ as well as $\sum_{n=m}^{M}a_{n}$ are Cauchy, thus they converge.

Moreover, due to the triangle inequality and the given assumption, one has that
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{n=m}^{M}a_{n}\right| \leq \sum_{n=m}^{M}|a_{n}| \leq \sum_{n=m}^{M}b_{n}
\end{align*}

Given that they all converge, we can take the limit to obtain the desired result, and we are done.

Am I missing any formal step? Please let me know if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nice, using the fact that the partial sums of $b_n$ convergence, all the series converge since there partial sums are all Cauchy. I don't think you missing any steps, it looks tight. If you're interested here's more for your consideration. The converges of $\sum_{n=m}^\infty |a_n|$ can also follow from what I learned as the monotone convergence theorem (not from Lebesgue integration) which says if a real sequences is monotone and bounded it converges. So, 
$$A_M := \sum_{n=m}^M |a_n| \le  \sum_{n=m}^M b_n \le \sum_{n=m}^\infty b_n <\infty$$
is monotone and bounded, and therefore converges. That $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ convergence absolutely follows exactly from the definition of absolute convergence,  since $\sum_{n=m}^\infty |a_n|$ converges. Triangle inequality together with the order-preserving property of limits does the rest, exactly as you ended it.